# Disable Back button in Title bar for Droid and WP in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Today I wanted to disable title bar button for Android and WindowsPhone as they have their own hardware back buttons and don't need another one in the title. As I started with pages coded in C# instead of XAML i knew about the OnPlatform directives and after I read [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/essential_xaml_syntax/) I thought of something like this:

```
<OnPlattform>
  <OnPlatform.Android>
    <NavigationPage HasBackButton="false" />
  </OnPlatform.Android>
  <OnPlatform.WinPhone>
    <NavigationPage HasBackButton="false" />
  </OnPlatform.WinPhone>
</OnPlattform>
```

This of course did not work. So i added the `NavigationPage.HasBackButton="false"` attribute to the ContentPage, which worked, but as far as i know this would disable the back button on all devices. In C# code I would do something like this:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, Device.OnPlatform(true, false, false));
//Or this:
Device.OnPlatform(
    () => { NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true); },
    () => { NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false); },
    () => { NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false); }
    );
```

So what do I have to do to get this to work in XAML?

Comment: Using NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton worked for me, You need to do this in the Constructor of the page however as this property is only viewed when creating the page.

Comment: Is it correct then that there is no way to do this in XAML? Do I have to do this in the code-behind?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is unfortunately no way to achieve this in XAML you will need to do this in the code-behind.

Comment: Okay, I will do so then. Thanks :)